# Savage Worlds Print and Play Adventure Deck

Tags: savage-worlds

Is there a list of the cards in the Adventure Decks.
Where I live retailers don't seem to be stocking Savage Worlds stuff and mail order from America is killing me financially because of massive postage and exchange rate so I end up spending $40 and waiting 2-6 weeks for a deck of cards I'm not even sure I'd find useful.

What I do have is time, pens and paper so I would like try and make a deck to try them out but I can't find a definitive list of what is written on them.

I would be happy to buy a PDF and try and print it but I'm having trouble finding one of those too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a time, Pinnacle Entertainment Group did release a PDF version of the first iteration of the adventure deck, which you could print out and put into card sleeves. However, they seemed to have stopped selling this sometime after they released the new version of the adventure deck that is currently sold today. Pinnacle has never released a PDF of the updated version.

I haven't found a card list of adventure cards online and I imagine that putting the card text out there is legally questionable. So I'm afraid that you may be out of luck with printing your own.

However, there are a couple of adventure deck addons that have been [released by various third party publishers in PDF form](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse.php?keywords=adventure%20deck&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=). Since you said you weren't sure if this was something you would be interested in getting, checking these out might give you an idea of the sort of effects that you can expect Pinnacle's adventure deck to have. You might even be able to use them in place of Pinnacle's deck.

Two that are free are:

- [Adventure Cards of the Dead](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/86098/Adventure-Cards-of-the-Dead)
- [Suzerain Adventure Deck](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/84380/Savage-Suzerain-Adventure-Deck)

Comment: Is there any chance that I might be able to get a look at the out of print cards somewhere?

Comment: @Peter Your best bet would be to [contact Pinnacle](https://www.peginc.com/about/contact-us/) about that. Their customer service is pretty good (they've always responded to my e-mails pretty quickly and in detail) and the staff is friendly, so if you explain your situation, there's a chance they will be willing to give you the out of print PDF.